# How to access Terraform server `count` in a datasource?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform script where I need to pass the `count.index` to the data block to get the correct IP. For example:

```
resource "null_resource" "provisioning_disk_config_server" {
  count      = var.config_server_count
  depends_on = [oci_core_volume_attachment.ISCSIDiskAttachment_config_server]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = data.oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint_reachable_ip.config_server_reachable_ip_address.ip_address

    user        = "opc"
    private_key = file(var.ssh_private_key)
  }.....
```

Datasource:

```
data "oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint_reachable_ip" "config_server_reachable_ip_address" {
  private_endpoint_id = oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint.rms_pe.id
  private_ip          = oci_core_instance.config_server[count].private_ip
}
```

How can I access/pass the server count index to the data block `oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint_reachable_ip` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would also have to use the `count` meta-argument:

```
data "oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint_reachable_ip" "config_server_reachable_ip_address" {
  count               = var.config_server_count 
  private_endpoint_id = oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint.rms_pe.id
  private_ip          = oci_core_instance.config_server[count.index].private_ip
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however this would give me the error "Because data.oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint_reachable_ip.config_server_reachable_ip_address has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances."

Comment: Actually this answer is correct. I had to pass in count like this `data.oci_resourcemanager_private_endpoint_reachable_ip.config_server_reachable_ip_address[count.index]'

Comment: Yup, that is another question I guessed you would have. :)